# Zonk! computer strategy decider design and logic

Tags: algorithm

I have a question about an **algorithm**. I have a function that is called computer_strategy_decider, it takes 6 dices(numbers) and decides the dices to keep and the dices to re-roll.

You may want to take in consideration the function description and the scoring part:

> **computer_strategy_decider()** – This function will decide which scoring strategy will be used. In
>   summary, the computer will always play safe and have a very simple strategy. The computer
>   will always choose the strategy that will give her the highest score (see scoring section). It will
>   check all the strategies and decide which one will give her the highest score. For example, if
>   the dices look as follows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 then there is no need to check other strategies the
>   scoring is 1500. If the scoring is as follows 1,1,1,5,5,5 then the computer will keep the first three
>   and roll the last three as this will give her 1000 scoring point rather than keeping 5,5,5 which
>   would give her 500.

Scoring rules:

> 1. Each 5 is worth 50 points.
> 2. Each 1 worth 100 points.
> 3. Any three-of-a-kind rolled at once is worth 100x the face value of a single die. (e.g.,
>      three two's are worth 200, three three’s are worth 300, three four’s are worth 400, three
>      five’s are worth 500 and three six’s are worth 600), apart from three one’s which worth
>      1000 (Note: they don’t have to be consecutive).
> 4. Six of a kind (e.g. 4 4 4 4 4 4 , 5,5,5,5,5,5,,...) are worth 1000 points.
> 5. A straight (1,2,3,4,5,6) is worth 1500 points (they do not need to be in that order, for
>      example, it could be 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4).

also:

> When dices are rolled, only one of the above can be used for scoring. Depending on the
>   number of dices kept, one of the strategies will be for scoring. For example, if the user rolls “1 1
>   1 1 1 1” and they decide to keep 1 of those, and roll again the rest, they will get 100 points. If
>   they decide to keep 3 of those and roll again the other three, they will get 1000 points. If they
>   decide to keep all, then they will get 1000 points. Please see “computer_strategy_decider”
>   function definition below for how computer will decide which strategy to use.

I want some help in solving this problem to be able to write this function to solve my problem.

```
int computer_stategy_decider(int csd_d1 , int csd_d2 ,int csd_d3 ,int csd_d4 ,int csd_d5 , int csd_d6){
int csd_result;

if(csd_d1+csd_d2+csd_d3+csd_d4+csd_d5+csd_d6==21){
    csd_result=1500;
    printf("I stop and Kept dices 1 2 3 4 5 6\nMy score: %d",csd_result);
}
else if(){}
```

above the only idea I could think of that is by summing the dices it can't work for all cases, only 6 of a kind. 111-111|222-222|333-333|444-444|555-555|666-666 & 123-456.